# Windows - Different startup programs after wake on lan computer start

Tags: windows, networking, ethernet, wake-on-lan

Can windows differentiate normal startup from wake on lan one?

I want to run additional programs at startup ONLY IF turning on was invoked by magic packet.

Is it possible? If so, then how should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use WMI to get the instance of [Win32_ComputerSystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102(v=vs.85).aspx), read the `WakeUpType` property, after WoL the value should be 5 “LAN Remote”